# license not found issue devart postgres sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, devart, dotconnect

i have developed an app using the devart dot connect control. I have deployed on the server, using iis. However, whenever i try to do anything with the database i get the license not found error. I have copied the license file into the bin and root of the application but to no avail. Any one else come across this error. IF so how did you manage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed the instructions provided in our [Licensing article](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/licensing.html)?
Please make sure that you have performed the steps described in the "Licensing ASP.NET applications" section.
If you have more questions, please contact us using our [forum](http://devart.com/forums/) or the [contact form](http://www.devart.com/company/contact.html).

Comment: ok sorted. i did the tools, postgre sql licensing and fixed the error there then rebuilt. Thanks i had read the article, hadn't found what i was looking for first time

Comment: This is a link only answer.